# python 3.6.1 require windows 7 service pack 1 to install

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to install python 3.6.1 on my windows 7 32 bit. But it always ask for Windows 7 service pack 1. I have already installed the windows 7 service pack 1 and my windows is updated completely. what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [release notes](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-361/), it requires an update to the C runtime libraries.

According to [this note](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/windows.html#embedded-distribution), Python needs the Microsoft C runtime for Visual Studio 2015, especially the file `ucrtbase.dll`. You can download that [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

<strike>For ms-windows users I would generally recommend using a Python distribution like [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) or [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/). They make life *a lot* easier if you want to use compiled extension modules like numpy. At `$WORK` I use Anaconda myself. It comes with a lot of extra stuff like numpy, IPython et cetera. And it has a  package management tool called `conda` if you want to get extra modules or update existing ones.</strike>

As of 2020, I actually recommend using the standard `python.org` distribution on ms-windows.
The issue with python requiring old compilers has been solved, and binary wheel packages for most significant C extension modules are available.